# Replace span tag with class to h4 tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have javascript string,

```
var str = '<div><p class="">Deleted content <span class="del cts-2">example</span></p></div>'.
```

I want to replace `<span class="del cts-2">` with `<h4>`.

Expected output is

```
var str = '<div><p class="">Deleted content <h4>example</h4></p></div>'
```

How can I do with pure javascript?

Comment: That's invalid syntax. Anyway, what do you want to replace with what? Did you proofread your question after you posted it? Anyway, to manipulate the DOM, use DOM manipulation routines, such as `replaceChild`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Its missing lot of details. Please add them.

Comment: I have escaped the code in OP's question. It was getting rendered and disappeared.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Sorry for missing valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with capturing group for that :

```
var str = '<div><p class="">Deleted content <span class="del cts-2">example</span></p></div>'
str = str.replace(/<span class="del cts-2">(.*?)<\/span>/g, "<h4>$1</h4>")
// now str == "<div><p class="">Deleted content <h4>example</h4></p></div>"
```

`(.*?)` parenthesis capture characters, and `$1` returns them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex:

```
str = str.replace(/span.*?>/g, 'h4>');
```